Solve blur effect on WooCommerce loop product images, without duplication issue
I’m using the latest versions of WordPress and WooCommerce with the latest Flatsome theme. I found an interesting snippet that solves the blur effect issue on product images. However, the code requires some tweaks:
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
function custom_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $product;
    $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail';
    $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );
    echo $product ? $product->get_image( 'full' ) : '';
}

When this code is enabled, the first row displays images in high quality as expected, but there is an additional row of product images that appears at the bottom, which I would like to remove.

Could anyone help me amend the code to remove the extra row of images from the front end?

You should try to use instead single_product_archive_thumbnail_size available filter hook that controls the image size used in the product grid/catalog, replacing your current code with:
add_filter( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', function( $size ) {
    return 'full';
}, 1000);

It should better work.

it didnt work and image are still blur - when Im comparing picture with above one its looks much more sharp and clear

Flatsome is a premium commercial theme, so you should ask their support, as they might have done some specific customizations.

May be the theme has added extra hooks or may be some conflict. But you can try like below just guess. May be it could help.
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_sizes' );
function custom_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'custom_size', 1920, 1920, true ); 
}

add_filter( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', function( $size ) {
    return 'custom_size';
}, 1000);

For more information on customizing image sizes in WooCommerce, please refer to the official documentation here.

it didnt work and image are still blur - when Im comparing picture with above one its looks much more sharp and clear

@oazawellness    add_image_size( 'custom_size', 600, 600, true ); adjust proportion to higher.
I have updated code.

its still doent apply the clarity of the picture which initial code does
